# How to inject Sequelize connection to module in NestJS?

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs

I am facing a problem, but I struggle to find any resources in NestJS documentation.

So, I got an app in NestJS that will be using multiple external custom modules, that must be also reusable in other apps. Let's say we want to import FilterModule and this module needs to use our Sequelize connection. This is just my idea of how it could work, but I really don't know how the DatabaseModule and DatabaseService would look.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        FilterModule.forRootAsync({
            import: [DatabaseModule],
            inject: [DatabaseService],
            useFactory: (databaseService: DatabaseService) => ({
                connection: databaseService.getConnection()
            })
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [
        AppService,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that in our external Filter module, we will be able to use our database connection. For example something like this would work (this code will be implemented in external module):

```
@Injectable()
export class FilterService {

    private connection: Sequelize;

    constructor(
        @Inject('CONNECTION') filterConnection: Sequelize
    ) {
        this.connection = filterConnection;
    }

    applyFilter() {
        // some code using connection
    }

}
```

And in our main app, we will be able to use code like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {


    constructor(
        private filterService: FilterService
    ) {
    }

    findAll(params: any) {

        const sequelizeQuery = this.filterService.applyFilter(params);

        // some other code...

    }

}
```

Is this possible in NestJS like this or do I need to look for some other ways? Thank you very much.

One note: Mentioned external modules are now written with pretty much basic Node.js and now I am looking for a way to rewrite them for better implementation in NestJS.